# Purpose of these capacitors in a DC-DC converter

Tags: pcb-design, dc-dc-converter

I am designing a PCB using the [QSC15024S28](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/942/SF_QSC150-1508695.pdf). It is an isolated DC-DC converter. This is the first time I am using an isolated DC-DC converter.

[image]

They have provided some kind of application circuit and table which has component values.

C3 and C4 should 4700pF.

- Why are these capacitors used?
- What are the parameters I need to consider while choosing the part numbers for these capacitors?

Can somebody help with these?

Comment: Accounting for their low value, these capacitors may be there for reducing common-mode conducted emissions. Did you ask the manufacturer directly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conducted_emissions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why these capacitors are used?

There's a transformer inside the converter and this transformer brings the isolation. And there's switching to make the DC-DC conversion job. So,

- There's a parasitic capacitance between the input and the output because of the existence of the transformer
- There'll be high-frequency (higher than switching frequency) noise at the output because of switching.

Looking at the values of those capacitors, they provide a short path for the --probably common-mode-- high-frequency noise to return to the input so that it can be filtered out by the input filter, thus increasing the EMI, specifically CE (conducted emission), performance.

If you don't place those capacitors, the noise may not return to the input because of the fact that the parasitic capacitance of the transformer is relatively low (a few tens of pF). So the output will have the noise relative to the input.

> What are the parameters I need to consider while choosing the part numbers for these capacitors?

In addition to what @frr has suggested in his/her [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/581253/purpose-of-these-capacitors-in-dc-dc-converter#comment1521317_581257), I'd suggest a ceramic capacitor with an XY rating if the input voltage is higher than ELV <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> ELV (**E**xtra **L**ow **V**oltage). There's no exact value defined but different standards in different regions define different values (e.g. IEC defines it as lower than 50 VRMS or 120 VDC (ripple-free)).

Comment: Yup - seen this noise a few times, e.g. in a USB/RS485 dongle with isolated 485 transceiver (DC/DC converter was used to power the isolated bus transceiver). The dongle maker forgot to include those capacitors. You have my upvote :-)

Comment: What parameters do I consider while selecting those capacitors?

Comment: @MightyBeard007 : how about 1) desired isolation voltage, 2) make sure the spectrum you need to suppress does not exceed the capacitor's own resonant frequency: https://ksim3.kemet.com/capacitor-simulation  If you want to be super-cautious, maybe lay out the board with a 0603 SMT footprint (or whatever you like), build a prototype, try looking at the spectrum of the noise produced by the DC/DC, and pick a capacitor accordingly. The resonant freq is a sweet spot, but maybe another objective: 3) desired level of isolation in terms of AC impedance across the isolation gap :-)

Comment: @MightyBeard007 see my edit.

Comment: A class Y capacitor is required *if* the isolation is safety-critical (ie. if someone could be exposed to the mains if the isolation were to fail.)

Comment: @OskarSkog you're right. I didn't check the exact part number and thus the possible maximum input voltage. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @RohatKılıç  I will be feeding 24V form batteries to this DC-DC converter